# what mysql format should i use for these decimals? (Google Maps co-ords)

Tags: mysql, google-maps

I have these two values i want to store:

```
        $a = '51.480092';
        $b = '-2.589397';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `DECIMAL(9, 6)`

`9` is the total number or digits, `6` is precision.

You need `3` digits for degrees since values from `-179` to `179` are possible.

This works on my `5.1.42`:

```
CREATE TABLE coords (lat DECIMAL(9, 6) NOT NULL, lon DECIMAL(9, 6) NOT NULL);

INSERT
INTO    coords
VALUES  ('51.480092', '-2.589397');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
FLOAT(2,6) signed
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/numeric-types.html